# How To Get Unique Value From Foreach

Tags: laravel, eloquent, charts, apexcharts

I Want to Send My Query Result to ApexCharts, but the results is not what i am intended

this is my query

```
 $queryPengadaanNonTender = DB::table('siapel_dokumen')
            ->where([['id_jenis_dokumen', '=','1'],['progres','=','100']])
            ->join('siapel_pengadaan', 'siapel_dokumen.id_jenis_pengadaan', '=', 'siapel_pengadaan.id')
            ->select(
                    DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT nama_paket) AS jml'),
                    DB::raw('jenis_pengadaan as pengadaan'),
                    DB::raw('tahun as tahun')
                    )
                    ->groupBy('pengadaan','tahun')
                    ->orderBy('tahun')
                    ->get();

            $pengadaanNonTender = $queryPengadaanNonTender->groupBy('pengadaan','tahun')->map(function ($groupedItems) {
                return $groupedItems->map(function ($item)  {
                    return [
                        'tahun' => $item->tahun,
                        'jml' => $item->jml,
                    ];
                });
            })->toArray();
```

And This Is The Output

```
"pengadaanNonTender" => array:7 [▶
    "Pengadaan Langsung - Barang" => array:2 [▶
      0 => array:2 [▶
        "tahun" => 2022
        "jml" => 9
      ]
      4 => array:2 [▶
        "tahun" => 2023
        "jml" => 20
      ]
    ]
    "Pengadaan Langsung - Konstruksi" => array:2 [▶
      1 => array:2 [▶
        "tahun" => 2022
        "jml" => 67
      ]
      6 => array:2 [▶
        "tahun" => 2023
        "jml" => 192
      ]
    ]
    "Tender-Konstruksi" => array:1 [▶
      2 => array:2 [▶
        "tahun" => 2022
        "jml" => 1
      ]
    ]
    "e-Katalog" => array:1 [▶
      3 => array:2 [▶
        "tahun" => 2023
        "jml" => 2
      ]
    ]
    "Pengadaan Langsung - Jasa Lainnya" => array:1 [▶
      5 => array:2 [▶
        "tahun" => 2023
        "jml" => 16
      ]
    ]
    "Pengadaan Langsung-Konsultan" => array:1 [▶
      7 => array:2 [▶
        "tahun" => 2023
        "jml" => 10
      ]
    ]
    "Pengadaan Langsung-Konsultansi" => array:1 [▶
      8 => array:2 [▶
        "tahun" => 2023
        "jml" => 9
      ]
    ]
  ]
  "pengadaanTender" => array:3 [▶
    "Tender-Konstruksi" => array:2 [▶
      0 => array:2 [▶
        "tahun" => 2022
        "jml" => 11
      ]
      3 => array:2 [▶
        "tahun" => 2023
        "jml" => 20
      ]
    ]
    "Pengadaan Langsung - Barang" => array:1 [▶
      1 => array:2 [▶
        "tahun" => 2023
        "jml" => 1
      ]
    ]
    "Tender Barang" => array:1 [▶
      2 => array:2 [▶
        "tahun" => 2023
        "jml" => 1
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

when i send the output to chart

this is what i get

[image]

i want to get unique year for my categories chart. i've tried everything but i still can't solve this.

PS : Sorry for my broken english

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, you are grouping the data by 'pengadaan' and 'tahun'. To achieve what you want, you should group the data only by 'tahun' and then organize the counts for each 'pengadaan' within that year. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
$queryPengadaanNonTender = DB::table('siapel_dokumen')
        ->where([['id_jenis_dokumen', '=', '1'], ['progres', '=', '100']])
        ->join('siapel_pengadaan', 'siapel_dokumen.id_jenis_pengadaan', '=', 'siapel_pengadaan.id')
        ->select(
            DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT nama_paket) AS jml'),
            DB::raw('jenis_pengadaan as pengadaan'),
            DB::raw('tahun as tahun')
        )
        ->groupBy('tahun', 'pengadaan') // Group by 'tahun' first
        ->orderBy('tahun')
        ->get();

    $pengadaanNonTender = $queryPengadaanNonTender->groupBy('tahun')->map(function ($groupedItems) {
        return $groupedItems->map(function ($item) {
            return [
                'tahun' => $item->tahun,
                'jml' => $item->jml,
                'pengadaan' => $item->pengadaan,
            ];
        });
    })->toArray();
```